# Mule: return the original message to flow (like For Each)

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

In For Each introdution we have: "The Foreach scope splits a collection into elements and processes them iteratively through the processors embedded in the scope, then returns the original message to the flow."

I would like to know if we have a form to return the original message to the flow when on the middle of the flow we have a processing with new message (payload) similar For Each works, but it is not a case to use For Each!

Example:

Flow (payload AA) -> ["Sub" flow (payload BB)] -> Flow (payload AA)

Is there a form to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an enricher  that stores the result of the `sub-flow` in a flowVar so that the original payload is not modified:

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars.someSubFlowResult]">
 <flow-ref name="mySubFlow" />
</enricher>
```

Or alternatively manually store the original payload into a flow variable on entering the flow and at the end of the flow set the payload back to the original payload using the flow variable. For example:

```
<set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]" />

<!-- do some other processing -->

<set-payload value="#[flowVars.originalPayload]" />
```